# Importance of Gavriel in Judaism

Tags: tanach, malach-angel

What is the status or rank or position or importance of  Gavriel as an Angel in Tanach or Oral Law and what causes it to be at that position or rank?

Answer (score 1):

Gabriel is a כרוב (Cherub), which is a level in the [hierarchy of angels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_angelic_hierarchy).

No person chose for him to be at that level.  Rather, cherub is his nature.  In the same way that we are people, Gabriel is a cherub.

Comment: what is cherub?

Comment: @Ali, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherub). They are angels who usually function as guardians.

Comment: No evidences from tanach? some consider him to be archangel and was it responsible for destroying Jerusalem?

Comment: @Ali, Yes, he is an archangel. The only time, as far as I can think of, that Gabriel appears in Tanakh is in Daniel chapters 8 and 9 to explain Daniel's visions.

Comment: so archangel>cherub?

Comment: @Ali, no archangel and cherub are not on the same continuum.  Cherub is a description of what type of angel he is. Archangel means that he is of some importance, although there does not seem to be any ordering of importance for the archangels.

Comment: How do you know he is a cruv?

Comment: @DoubleAA, Good point. I had thought that it says so specifically in Daniel, but it turns out that it does not. Daniel does describe Gabriel as flying, though, which indicates that it is quite likely that he is a כרוב